# How to display windows group membership and Permission access in a CIFS mount

Tags: linux, samba, mount, file-permissions, cifs

I have a CIFS mount point to a Windows Server from my Debian Linux box:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.10/users /mnt/users -o credentials=/etc/demo.smbpass
```

It mounts properly but all the permissions of all the files within the mount are all owned by root. I was hoping to be able to see inside the /mnt/users what files and/or folders are owned by certain users. I know I can assign a group and user ownership when it mounts but as I have some indexing being done I wanted to be able to only give certain users access to certain files. i.e. the same access they would have if they accessed them from the Windows environment.

net groupmap list" shows all my groupings in windows:

```
System Operators (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1004) -> daemon
Domain Users (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1002) -> users
Administrators (S-1-5-32-544) -> BUILTIN/administrators
Backup Operators (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1005) -> bin
Replicators (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1007) -> kmem
Domain Admins (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1000) -> DomainAdmins
Administrators (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1003) -> sys
Users (S-1-5-32-545) -> BUILTIN/users
Print Operators (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1006) -> lp
Domain Admins (S-1-5-21-437988629-1909902786-4261010331-1001) -> root
```

All the literature I find is all about Windows permissions accessing Samba shares from Linux, not the other way around. I don't even know if this is possible?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this, but I am also curious.

Comment: This would be dependent, of course, on your workstation and the server using the same directory service. That is, your Debian system would need to be bound to Active Directory in some capacity in order for the translation service to properly present groups and users as seen from the Windows server.

Answer (score 1):

from "man mount.cifs":

...
For servers which do not support the CIFS Unix extensions, the default uid (and gid) returned on lookup of existing files will be the uid (gid) of the person who executed the mount (root, except when mount.cifs is configured setuid for user mounts) unless the "uid=" (gid) mount option is specified.
...

i think this is not possible even with [SFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX) installed on the server, but i'm not 100% sure.